# Custom selector wont click because of display property

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have made a custom selector like

```
<div class="search">
                <input class="custom-selector" type="text" autocomplete="off" >
                <ul class="custom-options hidden">
                    <li>New York</li>
                    <li>Moscow</li>
                    <li>Baku</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

and whenever i focus on the  input the class hidden(only has display:none;) gets removed, and on blur(unfocus) it gets added back

```
$('.custom-selector').focus(function() {
    $(".custom-options").removeClass("hidden");
}).blur(function() {
    $(".custom-options").addClass("hidden");
})
```

On the next step i needed a function to onclick get the li value and copy it to the input ,but whenever i click on the li ,the input gets unfocused and the onclick function cant work on a display none,one solution i found was opacity 0 instead of display none for hidden class,is there more optimal and correct way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** You can add a `timeout` maybe?

```js
$('.custom-selector').focus(function() {
  $(".custom-options").removeClass("hidden");
}).blur(function() {
  setTimeout(function () { $(".custom-options").addClass("hidden") }, 350);
})

$('.custom-options > li').click(function(e) {
  $('.custom-selector').val($(this).text());
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search">
  <input class="custom-selector" type="text" autocomplete="off">
  <ul class="custom-options hidden">
    <li>New York</li>
    <li>Moscow</li>
    <li>Baku</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding css of `.hidden { display: none; }` to your code and see the output

Comment: this did it but with around 300ms+ and 100 sometimes it didnt register the click,thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of focusable elements and the :focus-within pseudo-class to not lose focus.

```js
$('.custom-options a').click(function (ev) {
  const selected = ev.target.textContent;
  $('.custom-selector').val(selected);
  ev.target.blur();
});
```

```css
.custom-options {
  display: none;
 }
.search:focus-within .custom-options {
  display: block;
}

.custom-options a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="search">
  <input class="custom-selector" type="text" autocomplete="off">
  <ul class="custom-options">
    <li>
      <a href="#">New York</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Moscow</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Baku</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```